# Fileshare link in firefox -

Tags: jquery, firefox, replace

I have a page which renders beautifully in IE but **NOT** in Firefox, the fileshare link is broken in Firefox.

In the sourcecodes, I have some URL links showing as:

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
.....
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
var ctl00_ctl42_g_9097923b_f721_43d1_be88_817032f0ffd8_ctl00results={ ...
<HHUrl>file:\u002f\u002fserver\u002ffolder\u002fTraining\u002fSummit2012\u002fB105_Jeavons.pptx<\u002fHHUrl>
....};
......
// ]]></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a Jquery to replace all the *file:\u002f\u002f* into the *file:\u002f\u002f\u002f\u002f\u002f\u002f\u002f\u002f* as shown below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">           
          $(function(){                     
            if(!$.browser.msie) {

                var replaceFSString = $('body').html().replace(/[file:\u002f\u002f]/g,'file:\\u002f\\u002f\\u002f\\u002f\\u002f');
                $('body').html(replaceFSString);           
            }          
    </script>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working.  Am I missing something?
Thanks for your help.

JPL

Answer (score 0):

I changed my src from "file:\server\dir\file.txt" to "file:///\server\dir\file.txt" as a quick and dirty solution since I'm operating on an intranet page.

Research:
http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2007/04/20/firefox-and-file-windows-unc-paths/